# show the selected drop down values to the another table

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am Have html table inside each td i have dropdown see below image how it looks like

[image]

if i select 1201 in dropdown  of second td also i want to change the value of to other dropdown with the same id,if the id is not matched it will not change

```
<td style="width:141px" id="CPH_GridView1_route'.$rows['net_id'].'" >
    <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" class="edit1 route '.$rows["net_id"].'" >
            <option value="-1">Choose..</option>';
            <option value="-1">1201</option>';
            <option value="-1">1101</option>';
    </select>
</td>
```

ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.edit1').on('change', function(){
            $.ajax({    type: "POST",
                url:"xxxxx/routestatusupdate.php",
                data:"value="+$(this).val()+"&rowid="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1]+"&clientid="+clientid+"&account_id="+account_id,
                success: function(res){
                    data = jQuery.parseJSON(res); //added line
                    alert('Saved Successfully!');
                    $('#CPH_GridView1_route').empty();
                    $('#CPH_GridView1_route').append(data.routeupdate);
                    $('.ajax').html($(this).val());
                    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                }
            });
        });
    });        
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could review your question? I'm having difficulty understanding what you want. The whole thing is a single run-on sentence with incorrect terminologies. For example, you have no check boxes.

Comment: sorry thanks for noticing its dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" class="edit1 route '.$rows["net_id"].'" onChange="foo()">
        <option value="-1">Choose..</option>';
        <option value="-1">1201</option>';
        <option value="-1">1101</option>';
</select>
```

```
<select name="second" id="mySelect" >
        <option value="-1">Choose..</option>';
        <option value="-1">1</option>';
        <option value="-1">2</option>';
</select>


 <script>
function foo(){
alert("cahnge");
document.getElementById("div1').innerHTML="<select name="second" id="mySelect" >
        <option value="-1">Choose..</option>';
        <option value="-1">1</option>';
        <option value="-1">2</option>';
</select>";

}
</script>
```